# Property 'environment' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'

Tags: angular6

I am trying to bind the value of the environment to the select dropdown using [(ngModel)]. I am getting an error "Property environment does not exist on HomeComponent."

home.component.html

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="envModel.environment"
[name]="environment" (change)="onEnvSelect(envModel.environment)">
<option [value]="env.id" *ngFor="let env of constLists.Environment"> 
{{env.value}}
</option>
</select>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { EnvironmentModel } from './home-landing.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  envModel = {} as EnvironmentModel;
}

onEnvSelect(env) {
    this.envModel.environment = env;
}
```

home.model.ts

```
export interface EnvironmentModel {
    environment: string;
}
```

Error Occuring:

Error in app\home.landing.component.html: "Property environment does not exist on HomeComponent."

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to put all code inside HomeComponent Class in Home.Component.ts

```js
import { EnvironmentModel } from './home-landing.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  envModel = {} as EnvironmentModel;


onEnvSelect(env) {
    this.envModel.environment = env;
}
}
```

and is it home-landing or home.model??